# How to Export a Embedable Google Map into the equivalent Map API JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Embedded maps and Google Maps JavaScript API are two ways to create custom maps:   https://developers.google.com/maps/web/

I have a non-programmer who created an embedded map without any JavaScript. His HTML code is sth like this :

```
<iframe class="maps-frame" src="//www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=Harrods,Brompton%20Rd,%20UK&amp;zoom=17&amp;key=AIzaSyD4iE2xVSpkLLOXoyqT-RuPwURN3ddScAI">     </iframe>
```

However we need add some more custom graphic on the map which is only achievable through the JavaScript API. The problem is it seems impossible to operate on an existing embedded map from JS.  So is it possible to convert the embedded  map to the equivalent JavaScript code that would have generated the same effect? Then I can take this generated JS code and add more JS code to do further customization. The embedded map has many markers and polygons created using Google's interactive tool. I hate to hand code the coordinates in JS to create these polygons. Hence the question.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644}, // put your data here 
          zoom: 8
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Find the demo at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple 
or follow the documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

Comment: Thanks but I am not sure this will help. I am not creating a map with JS. I have a map in an iframe and am asking if I can use JS to modify the look of the map in the iframe.  `<iframe class="maps-frame" src="//www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=Harrods,Brompton%20Rd,%20UK&amp;zoom=17&amp;key=AIzaSyD4iE2xVSpkLLOXoyqT-RuPwURN3ddScAI">
            </iframe>`